# how to open port 5222 on centos 5 cpanel

Tags: centos, iptables, port

How can I open ports tcp 5222 and udp 5222 on a centos 5 box running with cpanel,

I've tried doing it through iptables then when i've restarted the tables it freezes and timesout when i reload it seems that the iptables have reverted to what they were at before.

Comment: Admin panels are [off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (see [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258) for some reasons). The community has decided that we want to close both old and new questions when such an admin panel is relevant ([link 1](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8086), [link 2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what firewall you're running, on cPanel servers, it's common that apf or csf are running, type "csf" or "apf", if you get an answer for apf, I can't help you, never used it.

If you get something like csf help, edit /etc/csf/csf.conf and modify the TCP_IN and TCP_OUT variables and then issue "service csf restart".

If you get nothing for all those, you might just have a saved set, check out and see if there are any rules at /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Comment: hi, this is great, turns out i have csf and that worked within seconds of me changing it...

thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your method of connecting is getting cut off. How are you going about it? If it's by SSH, then you'll also need to open tcp/22. VNC uses 5900 for display :0, 5901 for display :1, etc. I'd also allow anything from interface "lo"; this ensures that the localhost can talk to itself, thereby enabling things like X and the font server, assuming you're using the GUI. It will also enable mysql, smtp, and other services. I haven't used postgresql, but I'm fairly sure it will use the same method.

The method of updating iptables you're using seems sound, otherwise.